# bash + write standard output and error to both logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, logs

in my bash script
I use the following approach in order to write every thing from standard output and standard error to log.txt

```
export LOG=/tmp/installation/log.txt

exec > $LOG 2>&1
```

so everything is writing to `/tmp/installation/log.txt`

but how to do the writing to two different logs path

lets say I want to write the same standard output and standard error both to 2 log files

then how is the syntax in this case ?

example

```
export LOG=/tmp/installation/log.txt
export LOG_I=/tmp/installation/log_info.txt
```

so both logs will get the same content

can we do like this?

```
export LOG=/tmp/installation/log.txt
export LOG_I=/tmp/installation/log_info.txt

exec > $LOG $LOG_I 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command

```
exec > $LOG $LOG_I 2>&1
```

would not quite work as it's the same as

```
exec $LOG_I > $LOG 2>&1
```

I.e., it would try to `exec` the command given by the unquoted expansion of `$LOG_I`.

---

To put data into multiple files, you will have to duplicate it.  This is done with `tee`.

For example,

```
log1="/tmp/logfile-1.txt"
log2="/tmp/logfile-2.txt"

exec > >( tee "$log1" >"$log2" ) 2>&1
```

This uses a process substitution to call `tee` for the standard output stream. The `tee` utility would take its input and save it to `$log1` and then redirect a copy of it to `$log2` (`tee` always produces a copy of its input on its standard output, but you could also have used `tee "$log1" "$log2" >/dev/null`).  Then we redirect our standard error stream to the same place as our standard output, so that `tee` may duplicate it in the same way.

To *append* to both logs, you would use

```
exec > >( tee -a "$log1" >>"$log2" ) 2>&1
```